# Should case variable be increment atomically?

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm writing Verilog code which iterate through the states of an FSM in order to perform a calculation in steps.  The application is done and running as desired, but for efficiency requirements I'm wondering the following.

I'm updating the case variable, "i", atomically as shown in excerpt 1 below, is this at all necessary to ensure it does not skip a step in my FSM?

Or is the method in excerpt 2 equally safe to run without a step being missed?

As excerpt two is twice as fast as excerpt one.

Before it is asked. Everything runs, everything is initialised prior to use, counters reset to 0 when finished and encased in a module.

---

Code for atomic update of "i"

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if( ITERATE ) i = i + 1; //Atomic increment of variable
  else begin
    case( i )
      0: ....
      .: .... 
      n: The case internals are not pertinent
    endcase
  end
  ITERATE = !ITERATE; //Trigger for atomic update of i
end
```

---

Code for non-atomic update of "i"

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  case( i )
    0: ....
    .: .... 
    n: The case internals are not pertinent
  endcase
  i = i + 1; //Non-atomic increment of variable
end
```

Comment: verilog is not a regular programming language. The above example is not really verilog. You need to use verilog processes, clocks, and other goodies. It is difficult to analyze your intent without other stuff, i.e. always blocks. I suggest you edit your example by adding real verilog to it.

Comment: The above is an excerpt of the particular code in question.  I'm not gonna post 500 lines of unrelated code, when this is the code in question.

The complete program I've written/designed is a runable and synthesizable verilog program.

Comment: The idea of an MCVE is that you, the asker, cut down your 500 lines of code to the bit that is relevant, but still keep it Compilable and Verifiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases your always blocks are executed only once per rising edge of clk. They will **not** be re-evaluated in the same delta cycle (unless you have glitches in clk itself).

The code inside any always block is executed sequentially as in other programming languages.

So, according to your samples, the first one will increment 'i' every **second** clock edge, while the second one will increment it every clock edge.

> I'm updating the case variable, "i", atomically as shown in excerpt 1 below, is this at all necessary to ensure it does not skip a step in my FSM?

I am not sure what you mean here, but `i` will be incremented one by one without skipping and the case statement in your fsm will have a chance to react to every value of 'i' in both cases. There will be a difference in timing due to your use of `ITERATE` in the first sample. Also, in the first example `i` will be incremented *before* the case statement and in the second sample, *after*. This is the other difference.

BTW, word `atomic` does not apply to any of the cases. What did you mean there?

Also note that you did not write your state machine according to general recommendations, splitting state and transition logic, also you most-likely misused blocking assignments in your samples. These probably are acceptable code samples for test bench, but they might not be good for RTL.

Comment: Atomic operations is a standard term used in paralell/multithreading/concurrent programming, meaning:
"Atomic operations in concurrent programming are program operations that run completely independently of any other processes."
-- https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3466/atomic-operation

The Java defines it as:"Atomic operation. An atomic operation is an operation which is performed as a single unit of work without the possibility of interference from other operations."

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It clarified my belief so I can take the bother of implementing it.

Comment: verilog is a concurrent language but **not** multi-threading. It means that all statements are atomic in the sense you mentioned. Moreover, all always block content is atomic to some extend (unless you intentionally insert simulation control statements).  Generically speaking 'atomic' is not applicable to verilog programming.